# How can use grid system for dividing in two parts in same container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.story_design
{
 background:#5cb85c;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 50px 65px 58px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container story_design">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="panel-body">
       <h2>Online Backup</h2>
       <h3>Continuous automatic file backup</h3>
       <a class="expand btn btn-success">LEARN MORE</a>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
      <ul class="panel-body">
       <p class="tagLine">SugarSync's online backup service works quietly in the background without interfering with your productivity.</p>
       <p class="callOut">Restore all your data</p>
       <p class="callOut">File version control and recovery</p>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

In this code there is two section which were divided in to part of screen by using grid system but it's not working kindly suggest some example or provide right way to written a code.

Answer (score 0):

Your div with 'container' class should be above the div with 'row' class.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="container story_design">
           <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h2>Online Backup</h2>
                            <h3>Continuous automatic file backup</h3>
                            <a class="expand btn btn-success">LEARN MORE</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <ul class="panel-body">
                            <p class="tagLine">SugarSync's online backup service works quietly in the background without interfering with your productivity.</p>
                            <p class="callOut">Restore all your data</p>
                            <p class="callOut">File version control and recovery</p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```